# Background task freezing app screen [Flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

guys!

In one of my flutter apps, i'm running some tasks in database at background. While the task is running, the user are free to interact with the screen. In this process, when the task reach a specific point (this specific point has a lot of database operations) the screen freezes, until the this specific point ends.

someone already did something like that? someone knows a solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using asynchronous methods? Like async/await, or something like this? As the Dart documentation says:

> Asynchronous operations let your program complete work while waiting for another operation to finish. Here are some common asynchronous operations:
>
> - Fetching data over a network.
> - Writing to a database.
> - Reading data from a file.

If is your case, try transform your function into async, like

```
String getMyUser() async {
  String myUser = await fetchDatabase();
  return myUser;
}
```

Check the [documentation](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await)

Comment: Thanks by ur answer!